# Can you cut up frames/packets and combine them anonymously?

Tags: anonymity, packet

Is it possible to somehow cut up a packet and send it from multiple IPs into parts and send them to one IP address to reconstruct a semi-anonymous packet/frame? 
Can frames have their source faked?
Does this somehow relate to the Tor network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes, you can mask the source IP

Nothing stops you from writing a false source IP address, just like nothing stops you from changing the "From" field on a letter. In fact, IP packets and letters are remarkably similar.

> What happens if I change the source address?

The answer is quite simple: You will not get a response. The IP address in the source address will get a response. This technique is used in some DDoS attacks to mask the origin of the attack, or to cause the server to reply to the server you actually want to attack.

> Can this be stopped?

Yes, in a remarkably simple way. Imagine you live in New York and go to a local post office, wishing to send a letter to France. As the sender's address, you state "The White House, Washington DC". It's very likely that an attentive postal worker will reject your package (and possibly notify authorities, but that's beside the point).

How could the postal worker know it was fake? Because the postal worker knows which "Source Addresses" are legitimate - namely those from New York. Any source address outside of that will be rejected. Network Ingress Filtering is a technique that works the same way.

ISPs know the range of addresses they hand out (e.g. `203.0.113.0/24`, so `203.0.113.1` to `203.0.113.254`), so any IP packet coming from that network with a source address in this range will be accepted, and the rest rejected.

## About the other questions

> Can you chop up an IP packet and send it from multiple IP addresses?

Yes, this is actually done regularly by routers all over the world. It's how the internet is designed to work. It also doesn't give you any kind of anonymity, because the Internet Protocol wasn't designed to be anonymous.

For further reading, Wikipedia has an excellent article describing [IP Fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_fragmentation).

> Does this somehow relate to the Tor network?

No.

Comment: I've learned quite a bit about networking already, but I don't remember anything about packets/frames getting chopped into pieces, which get sent from different origins to have such kind of a weird spread of information. Would using proxies etc ensure some anonymity by doing that? (for example each frame getting cut and sent into multiple proxies in a chain or something similar)

Comment: @SirMuffington Wikipedia has an excellent article describing [IP Fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_fragmentation).

Comment: The article did not help me find out whether this scenario would work.. It help on the IP Fragmentation part though.

Comment: @SirMuffington Cutting up the IP packet and sending it over multiple paths is how the internet works. The packets containing this comment may all take vastly different routes, both to the Stack Exchange servers, and back to you.

Comment: Yes, but they all originated from a single source and not multiple ones.

Comment: @SirMuffington If you would split up one package into several, and then change the source address, then the reassembly of the packet at the source would fail and it would be discarded.